# TPL does not start task

Tags: c#, timer, task-parallel-library

I do the following:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
        receiveDataTimer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("TIMER DONE");
    }

private void EventDataReceived(Message msg)
    {
       dataQue.Enqueue(msg.data);
       var context = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Application.Current.Dispatcher);

            if(receiveDataTimer.Enabled==false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("START TASK");
                tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Work(tokenSource.Token, MaxPoints), tokenSource.Token);
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Update(context, tokenSource.Token), tokenSource.Token);             
                receiveDataTimer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                receiveDataTimer.Interval=3000;
            }

    }
```

Basically, there is a timer which sets the token to cancel the two tasks. After A while the timer is restarted and the two tasks should be started again. But they don't.

Can someone tell me why? Both only start the first time running the application.

I added more code now. When data is received from serial port, the EventDataReceived is called. I debugged and the timer does what it should.

Data received -> start task -> start timer -> (if 3s no data received) stop tasks -> (if data received) restart task and timer.

But tasks do not start again.

Comment: Can you give us more code? You say that the timer should start them again.. but you have a check to see if the time is enabled.. is it enabled? Have you debugged this yourself?

Comment: I added more code now. In general I can see that everything works as it should. Only the tasks do not start (or at least the functions "work" and "update" are not called a second time).

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Are the `StartNew()` methods actually called?